# Minecraft, reactivate Iron Farm NBT Data

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

we built a fully working Iron Farm on our Survival Vanilla Server after this video:

.

It worked for about a month, then i accidently broke it. Now all 32 Villages fell together into one Village which is horrible because it was pretty annoying to built this farm.

We tried:

1. Shutdownserver
2. Reupload the NBT File for the Iron Farm which has the 32 Villages split up still
3. Restart the Server
4. We also refilled the Dropper with the roses before that

It still renders all 32 Villages into one after restarting the server, even after we replaced the NBT File with the old - correct - version.

Anyone has any solutions on how to reactivate the farm with 32 Villages without the whole door placing mechanism?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you update Minecraft? They added multiple village in the same area protection, they will merge in 1.8.

Comment: @EliasBenevedes: The Video explains how to build a Working Iron Farm in MC 1.8. We built this farm in 1.8 and it works perfectly. I just broke it by mistake, now we want to get it to work again. The reupload of the NBT Data for the 32 Villages should do it, but it doesn't work.